Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta Api, error "Encountered too much data for one HASH JOIN partition" BetaAnalyticsDataClient RunReport
I am using the following code to get report from Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta Api
var client = new BetaAnalyticsDataClientBuilder
{
    GrpcAdapter = RestGrpcAdapter.Default
}.Build();

return client.RunReport(reportRequest);

It works for most of the clients, and for most of the dates.
However for some dates it keep throwing following error:
Grpc.Core.RpcException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Status(StatusCode="InvalidArgument", Detail="0th request: f1::BAD_REQUEST_ERROR: http://go/f1error/too_much_data_in_hash_table.md Encountered too much data for one HASH JOIN partition while executing the query. The data was more finely partitioned 3 times but one of the partitions was too large every time.")
  Source=Google.Api.Gax.Grpc
  StackTrace:
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.Rest.RestMethod.<ReadResponseAsync>d__11`1.MoveNext()
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.Rest.RestCallInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`2.<<BlockingUnaryCall>b__0>d.MoveNext()
   at Google.Api.Gax.TaskExtensions.WaitWithUnwrappedExceptions(Task task)
   at Google.Api.Gax.TaskExtensions.ResultWithUnwrappedExceptions[T](Task`1 task)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.Rest.RestCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<BlockingUnaryCall>b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext`2 ctx)
   at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext`2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation`2 continuation)
   at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method`2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)
   at Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta.BetaAnalyticsData.BetaAnalyticsDataClient.RunReport(RunReportRequest request, CallOptions options)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall.GrpcCallAdapter`2.CallSync(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<WithRetry>b__0(TRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall`2.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<WithCallSettingsOverlay>b__1(TRequest req, CallSettings cs)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCall`2.Sync(TRequest request, CallSettings perCallCallSettings)
   at Google.Analytics.Data.V1Beta.BetaAnalyticsDataClientImpl.RunReport(RunReportRequest request, CallSettings callSettings)

I tried using different batch Sizes: 100K, 50k, 10k, 1k
but is stays same for those particular dates

Have you tried using the default (gRPC) adaptor?

Hi @DazWilkin, sorry didn't your response earlier.
ya have tried this, it give same error.
BetaAnalyticsDataClient  client = BetaAnalyticsDataClient.Create();

var response = client.RunReport(reportRequest);


StackTrace is slightly different:
StackTrace:
at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.HttpClientCallInvoker.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](Method2 method, String host, CallOptions options, TRequest request)    at Grpc.Core.Interceptors.InterceptingCallInvoker.<BlockingUnaryCall>b__3_0[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest req, ClientInterceptorContext2 ctx)
at Grpc.Core.ClientBase.ClientBaseConfiguration.ClientBaseConfigurationInterceptor.BlockingUnaryCall[TRequest,TResponse](TRequest request, ClientInterceptorContext2 context, BlockingUnaryCallContinuation2 continuation)
at
